# AWS s3 service and symfony user's role

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am new to AWS and i have one problem. I have a symfony 3 app and a s3 bucket now i want some file to be accessible for users with role admin only. but looks like i can't link AWS s3 and symfony user's role.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should adapte your configuration AWS s3 (Canned ACL):
look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-s3-acls.html)  and with symfony at [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/cache-resolver/aws_s3.html#object-get-options)
Hope it is useful !